# Does ownership of a large quantity of ETH set you up for the impending smart contract economy better than the have-nots?

Tags: ether, economics, cryptoeconomics

We can agree that ETH is not held by people to purchase goods in the same way that Bitcoin does in practice by today's standards,

so instead, can the utility of hording ETH be explained away with the claim that, with economies moving towards all-out digitalized smart contracts for the transaction of any underlying real asset, those holding large amounts of ETH now, will be better positioned in the future to avail of and be at a functionally  higher advantage in that new economy than those who decided to not collect ETH during its growth, having dismissed it in our present day for its potential as the basis of that impending new economy?

How credible is this argument for collecting ETH, given that, when that new economy comes around, those who never held ETH could simply convert their wealth whenever the time comes that smart contracts do become the norm, despite them having foregone the growth of having held it during its development (our present day)? What I mean is that, assuming the new smart contract economy will all be based on ETH, then holding ETH is necessary to participate in that new economy

Answer (score 2):

The new smart contract economy will not be based on ETH. The main trand of development in this sphere now is the creation of private or permissioned intercorporate, interbank and regulatory networks (under the management of Central Banks) based on DLT-platforms of the enterprise category: Quorum, Highperleger Factoric, Corda and so on.

ETH is now more an investment platform, but the process of creating DFA platforms supported by local financial regulators at the legislative and organizational level is already underway.

Comment: if not ETH, which cryptocurrency powers the DLT platforms like Corda you listed? what does DLT and DFA stand for

Comment: These systems usually don't use cryptocurrencies at all. Either electronic payment documents are transmitted in the system, and settlements are made in fiat currency from the outside, or the digital representation of fiat currency on the "mirrors" of real bank accounts is used for settlements (as for card processing).