# Why won't Ethereum underlie the emerging smart contract economy?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, economics, cryptoeconomics

The following [post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/92936/does-ownership-of-a-large-quantity-of-eth-set-you-up-for-the-impending-smart-con/92945#92945) says

> The new smart contract economy will not be based on ETH. The main
> trand of development in this sphere now is the creation of private or
> permissioned intercorporate, interbank and regulatory networks (under
> the management of Central Banks) based on DLT-platforms of the
> enterprise category: Quorum, Highperleger Factoric, Corda and so on.

Is this the opinion of the minority, that Ethereum will not succeed in underlying the impending smart contract economy? Whereas the majority of people already identify Ethereum to have first mover advantage and as being the one to take the lion's share of all smart contract interactions?

This is the first time I've ever even heard of  Quorum, Highperleger Factoric, Corda. And the quote is sounding alot like the governments would have all their hands in the new smart contract economy, when the central theme of the crypto revolution is to overthrow government overwatch.

Comment: This site is about technical issues you won't get many answers about other issues. I'd suggest to ask on reddit.com/r/ethereum.

Comment: technical issues with the tags "economics" and "cryptoeconomics"? Philosophical questions should still belong

Comment: Some rules changed over time there's an option to close questions if they are subjective. There's a meta community where you can ask if they should be allowed https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com. In any case there aren't many participants lately.

Comment: As per Ismael's response, questions likely to be answered with opinions aren't necessarily useful to the wider community, who may or may not agree with the accepted answer. (This falls under: "This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers." in the community moderation options.)